# Could not run Calabash-android on docker

Tags: docker, automation, android-virtual-device, calabash-android

I am integrating a Calabash-android test on docker. The entire setting up and running Calabash in my local was quite easy and when it comes to docker I could not run the test yet. I have been trying this for the past two weeks and did not get any positive response while trying to run the emulator. Finally according to the suggestion from an android expert I have end up using the below-given docker file,

```
FROM tracer0tong/android-emulator
RUN apt-get -y install python-software-properties && apt-add-repository -y ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng && apt-get update && apt-get -y     install  r uby2.2
#install android dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
RUN gem install calabash-android
ENV ANDROID_HOME /usr/local/android-sdk
ENV GRADLE_HOME /usr/local/gradle
ENV ANDROID_SDK_HOME $ANDROID_HOME
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/tools
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/platform-tools
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

After building the image by using the above dockerfile everything seems installed properly but whenever I try to run the emulator it is raising an error as if the emulator does not exist. And the below one as well. It would be appreciated if someone come forward to give a helping hand to fix the blocker.

> appt is not found

Comment: what shows `docker build` and when you launch your container `docker logs container_id` anything in  `docker events`?

Comment: also ther is not CMD or ENTRYPOINT in  your Dockerfile, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: I am sorry, I could not give a reply to your comments since I have postponed this task, @user2915097 : docker logs gives the response "Switch to inspect mode.
Switch to inspect mode". And nothing is returning for the command "docker events".